# CDK Unit test using jest and NodeJsFunction

Tags: amazon-web-services, unit-testing, aws-lambda, jestjs, aws-cdk

I faced issue when trying to writs units for my CDK project.

Stack is creating, pretty simple one:

```
-> APIGateway (Rest)
  -> POST endpoint pointing to lambda
-> Lambda
```

I have very simple unit:

```js
describe("Test WebhookProxyStack", () => {
  it("template must be defined", () => {
    const app = new cdk.App();
    const processorStack = new WebhookProxyStack(app, "dev" as never);
    const template = Template.fromStack(processorStack);
    expect(template).toBeDefined();
  });
});
```

Lambda code is

```js
const lambda = new NodejsFunction(scope, name, {
    runtime: Runtime.NODEJS_14_X,
    handler: `handler`,
    entry: require.resolve(
      "@webhook-proxy/src/XXX.ts",
    ),
  });
```

When I deploy CDK, everything is bundling (via local esbuild) fine, no errors, but when trying to run this unit I am getting error like:

```sh
Error: Failed to bundle asset WebhookProxy-dev/lambda-name/Code/Stage, bundle output is located at /private/var/folders/g_/7s34q40s3rg40280qhrvx5fm0000gn/T/cdk.outQhujdM/bundling-temp-1309d84e2e3633714893bccef1ab36748a1c6088468eb4607da3325bcd2d7058-error: Error: bash -c yarn run esbuild --bundle "{OUTPUT_PATH}" --target=node14 --platform=node --outfile="/private/var/folders/g_/7s34q40s3rg40280qhrvx5fm0000gn/T/cdk.outQhujdM/bundling-temp-1309d84e2e3633714893bccef1ab36748a1c6088468eb4607da3325bcd2d7058/index.js" --external:aws-sdk run in directory {PROJECT_PATH} exited with status 127

at AssetStaging.bundle (/Users/XXX/Sites/XXX/webhook-proxy/node_modules/aws-cdk-lib/core/lib/asset-staging.ts:395:13)
at AssetStaging.stageByBundling (/Users/XXX/Sites/XXX/webhook-proxy/node_modules/aws-cdk-lib/core/lib/asset-staging.ts:243:10)
at stageThisAsset (/Users/XXX/Sites/XXX/webhook-proxy/node_modules/aws-cdk-lib/core/lib/asset-staging.ts:134:35)
at Cache.obtain (/Users/XXX/Sites/XXX/webhook-proxy/node_modules/aws-cdk-lib/core/lib/private/cache.ts:24:13)
at new AssetStaging (/Users/XXX/Sites/XXX/webhook-proxy/node_modules/aws-cdk-lib/core/lib/asset-staging.ts:159:44)
at new Asset (/Users/XXX/Sites/XXX/webhook-proxy/node_modules/aws-cdk-lib/aws-s3-assets/lib/asset.ts:72:21)
at AssetCode.bind (/Users/XXX/Sites/XXX/webhook-proxy/node_modules/aws-cdk-lib/aws-lambda/lib/code.ts:180:20)
at new Function (/Users/XXX/Sites/XXX/webhook-proxy/node_modules/aws-cdk-lib/aws-lambda/lib/function.ts:348:29)
at new NodejsFunction (/Users/XXX/Sites/XXX/webhook-proxy/node_modules/aws-cdk-lib/aws-lambda-nodejs/lib/function.ts:50:5)
```

Any hint\help what could be wrong with bundling this lambda when units and how to pass it ?

Another question is why this lambda must be build when executing units?

**Info:**

- AWS CDK v2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

##### Esbuild error in test when building Lambda

Not a fix, but a diagnostic/workaround: pass `bundling: {forceDockerBundling: true }` in the lambda props to use Docker instead of esbuild for [local bundling](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_lambda_nodejs-readme.html#local-bundling).

##### Why is the lambda built when executing units?

Stacks need to be synth-ed to be tested.  CDK [generates a hash for assets](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/assets.html#assets_details) as part of the synth process.  The source hash is *"used at construction time to determine whether the contents of an asset have changed."*